# Using the Google Maps API3, how can I clear a map of all custom overlays

Tags: dictionary, google-maps-api-3

How can I clear a Map of all custom overlays?

I do not want my markers removing, instead, I only want the custom shape overlays that I have created to be removed. (circles, polygons, ect)

upd:resolved

Comment: Really badly phrased question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of the overlays you want to remove simply iterate over that collection calling setMap(null):

```
function RemoveOverlays() {
    for (var i = 0; i < overlays.length; i++) {
        overlays[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```